# cmake cxx flags only at compile time

Tags: cmake, flags

I wanted to know if there is a way to pass some flags to the compiler (g++) only at compile time and not at the linking.
Let me explain with an example: I would like to build my program this way:

```
g++ -c source1.cpp -o source1.o
g++ -c source2.cpp -o source2.o
g++  source2.o source1.o -o myProgram.c
```

to do this I have created a CMakeLists.txt file that contains:

```
PROJECT(myProgram)
include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc")
aux_source_directory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src" SRC_FILES)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
```

then add this line to put the "-c" flag to the compiler:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -c")
```

But in this way, cmake add the "-c" flag always, even when g++ is doing the linking, ie:

```
g++ -c source1.cpp -o source1.o
g++ -c source2.cpp -o source2.o
g++ -c  source2.o source1.o -o myProgram.c
```

and logically myProgram will not be created because the g++ does not run linking (-c in the last instruction).

How do I use the flag "-c" (or any other flag) only at compile?

Comment: Did you try to run your code? No needs to specify "-c" option to compiler, when using CMake. CMake knows how to build sources, and how to link them after.

Comment: ok, I do not doubt that CMake knows how to build sources, and how to link them after.

Maybe in this case the "-c" flag is useless, but it's just an example, there may be cases where I need to use some flags with g ++ only at compiler time, and maybe other flags just at link time.
Cmake covers this situation.?

Comment: Even for gcc, compilation and linking uses disjoint set of options. For CMake, `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` are *compile* options(flags). Link options can be specified using `target_link_libraries` and some other cmake commands.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -c")
```

try

```
add_compile_options(-c)
```

No clue why though. You can use multiple space separated options in the same add_compile_options.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this "CMakeLists.txt"

```
PROJECT(prima_prova)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE 1)

include_directories("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/inc")
aux_source_directory("${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/src" SRC_FILES)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_FILES})
```

when I run cmake .. and make, I get this:

```
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/build"
make -f CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/build.make     CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/build"
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/inc    -o     CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o -c    /home/massimi/Scrivania/test/src/f1.cpp
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/inc    -o     CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c    /home/massimi/Scrivania/test/src/main.cpp
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f2.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -I/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/inc    -o   CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f2.cpp.o -c    /home/massimi/Scrivania/test/src/f2.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable prima_prova
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/link.txt --  verbose=1
/usr/bin/c++      CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o    CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/main.cpp.o    CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f2.cpp.o  -o prima_prova -rdynamic 
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/build"
```

when I add this line in the file "CMakeLists.txt":

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -c")
```

when I run cmake .. and make, I get this:

```
make[2]: uscita dalla directory "/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/build"
make -f CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/build.make   CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/build
make[2]: ingresso nella directory "/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/build"
[ 25%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -c -I/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/inc    -o   CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o -c     /home/massimi/Scrivania/test/src/f1.cpp
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/main.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -c -I/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/inc    -o     CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/main.cpp.o -c    /home/massimi/Scrivania/test/src/main.cpp
[ 75%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f2.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++    -c -I/home/massimi/Scrivania/test/inc    -o     CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f2.cpp.o -c    /home/massimi/Scrivania/test/src/f2.cpp
[100%] Linking CXX executable prima_prova
/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/link.txt --verbose=1  
/usr/bin/c++    -c   CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o    CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/main.cpp.o   CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f2.cpp.o  -o prima_prova -rdynamic 
c++: warning: CMakeFiles/prima_prova.dir/src/f1.cpp.o: linker input file     unused because linking not done
```

The flag "-c" or any iother flag in the variable CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS has been added always, even during linking, not only when  is compiling sources.

Answer (score -1):

`CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` variable is used in command line only when CMake is compiling sources. During linking `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` (and flags set by modifying target properties) are used, even if `g++` is used as linker executable.

Comment: As OP showed it appeared that, whenever CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS is modified (e.g. add -std=c++1y) cmake start to use CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS for linking as well.